# Abaqus: efficiently export large xy data set from Abaqus

Tags: abaqus

I am trying to export XY data objects from sets of the size of 20-40k elements, but Abaqus is slowing down considerably, and even crashing. In fact, when I create the xy data, Abaqus gives me a warning saying that "*the number of xyDataObjects is very large, and might cause performance issues*". And so it does.

My usual procedure to is to create the xy data and then export in rpt format. Can someone suggest another method less prone to crashing? Would it be more efficient to divide the output element set into two or more subsets, and concatenate them after exporting?

Comment: If you can, export the data using a field report instead of XY data because XY data is usable for a smaller number of nodes or elements.

Comment: @hgazibara Would this allow me to export the field output for several time slices at once?

Comment: If by "time slices" you mean steps and frames, then yes.

Comment: @hgazibara I tried to do this, but it only allows me to export one frame at a moment. Also, it does not allow me to select sets. Do you know of a workaround?

Comment: You iterate over all frames and append the results to the same file. The workaround for the sets is creating a display group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method recommended by @hgazibara in the comments is certainly sufficient, but it is laborious.

An easier method, I found, is a package called Abaqus2Matlab, which scrapes any variable you want from the odb. See here: http://www.abaqus2matlab.com/